# How can a Shared Data Extension be accessed by API using DE's External key?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, retrieve

When We tried to access Shared Data Extension using API, we have received the error message as '**Unable to process DataExtension::Row request due to unable to find DataExtension based on CustomerKey**'.

At the same time, Data Extension in the BU was accessed successfully using External key.

Is there a way to retrieve data from  Shared DE using its External Key via API object? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though they are visible with in the UI of the BU you are integrating with, Shared Data Extensions always “belong” to the Enterprise BU.

Hence your API call needs to authenticated using a token obtained in the scope of the MID of your Enterprise BU. Meaning if you update both local and shared BUs, you will need to “juggle” multiple authentication tokens.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps